# Fast way of getting all sublists of a list

Tags: python, optimization, combinations

I recently bombed a coding interview because I wasn't able to generate all possible sublists of a list fast enough. More specifically: (using python)

- We're given a list of string numbers `["1", "3", "2", ...]`
- How many sublists of this list of size 6, concateanted, are dividable by 16?
- Note that though the elements in the original list may not be unique, you should treat them as unique when constructing your sublists. E.g. for `[1, 1, 1]` a sublist of the first two 1's and the last two 1's are different sublists.

Using `itertools.combinations` I was able to generate all my sublists fast enough, but then looping through all those sublists to determine which one's were "dividable" by 16 was too slow.

So is there a way to create the sublists at the same speed (or faster) than `itertools.combations`, checking while each sublist as I'm creating it to see if they're divisable by 16?

Any insight would be very appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean for a list of strings to be "dividable by 16"?  Do you mean the sum of the int values?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "list of size 6 are dividable by 16". Do you mean the sum of the values in the list?

Comment: By sublist size, did you mean the sum of the elements of the sublist?

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry I should have been more clear. I meant is the concatenation divisable by 16

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list.
find the smallest list (by length)having sum at least 16 and divisible by it(say s).
then check all size list from s to 6.
That should reduce the number of size exponentially since bigger the length of sublist the lesser the number of sublists

Comment: Also if s is 3 check only for sublists of size 3 and 6. if s is 4 or 5 or 6 check only for s. if s is 2 check only for 2 and 4 and 6.Do you get it?